# How to display a control dynamically in wpf?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I have a collection with fields cityname, statename and countryname and I bind that collection to my wpf form. I want to display the cityname in a Textbox, the statename in a combobox and the countryname in a combobox. All the textboxes and comboboxes should come dynamically. How can I do this job?

Any one suggest me how to design this form dynamically in wpf using MVVM 
I am trying to do this code but not get result properly

```
<UserControl.Resources>

<DataTemplate x:Key="IntegerTemplate">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBox Margin="10,0,0,0" x:Name="IntegerTemplate" Grid.Column="1" MaxLength="{Binding Path=CardField.MaximumLength}" Text="{Binding Path=CardField.FieldData, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="StringTemplate">
    <DockPanel>
        <ComboBox Margin="10,0,0,0" x:Name="cmbFieldData" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=CardField.FieldData, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate">
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="dataTemplate">
    <ContentControl x:Name="MyContentControl"  Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}"/>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CardField.FieldTag}" Value="City">
                <Setter TargetName="MyContentControl" Property="ContentTemplate"
                   Value="{StaticResource IntegerTemplate}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CardField.FieldTag}" Value="State">
                <Setter TargetName="MyContentControl" Property="ContentTemplate"
                   Value="{StaticResource StringTemplate}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CardField.FieldTag}" Value="Country">
                <Setter TargetName="MyContentControl" Property="ContentTemplate"
                   Value="{StaticResource StringTemplate}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <!-- and so on -->
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

we are using this code in our xaml page

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="items"
 ItemsSource="{Binding}"
 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dataTemplate}"
/>
```

**UPDATE:**
i am trying to do this following code:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tbFieldTag" Cursor="Hand" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=CardField.FieldTag}" />
            <ItemsControl x:Name="items"
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dataTemplate}"/>
```

In that i got Value of TextBlock but i am not getting the value in ItemTemplate. so where I doing wrong?

Comment: Your approach seems valid to me. What is not working for you?

Comment: i am not getting dynamic control in this code

Comment: @ColinE: I am using "data template selector" in my viewmodel as specified by Vladimir Dorokhov: in below answer, but unfortunately the class is not called during debug.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1) data template selector

```
  public class CardFieldTemplateSelector : IValueConverter
    {

            public DataTemplate CityNameTemplate { get; set; } 

            public DataTemplate StateNameTemplate { get; set; }


            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                string fieldTag = (string) value;
                switch (fieldTag)
                {
                    case "City":
                        return CityNameTemplate;
                    case "State":
                        return StateNameTemplate;
                }

                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
        }
```

2) XAML:

```
 <selectors:CardFieldTemplateSelector x:Key="cardFieldTemplateSelector">
   <selectors:CardFieldTemplateSelector.CityNameTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
      <DockPanel>
        <TextBox Margin="10,0,0,0" x:Name="IntegerTemplate" Grid.Column="1" MaxLength="{Binding Path=CardField.MaximumLength}" Text="{Binding Path=CardField.FieldData, Mode=TwoWay}" />
      </DockPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </selectors:CardFieldTemplateSelector.CityNameTemplate>

   <selectors:CardFieldTemplateSelector.StateNameTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
      <DockPanel>
        <ComboBox Margin="10,0,0,0" x:Name="cmbFieldData" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=CardField.FieldData, Mode=TwoWay}" />
     </DockPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </selectors:CardFieldTemplateSelector.StateNameTemplate>
 </selectors:CardFieldTemplateSelector>

<DataTemplate x:Key="dataTemplate">
   <ContentControl x:Name="MyContentControl" 
                   Content="{Binding}"
                   ContentTemplate="{Binding CardField.FieldTag, Converter={StaticResource cardFieldTemplateSelector}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<ItemsControl x:Name="items"
 ItemsSource="{Binding}"
 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dataTemplate}"/>
```

Comment: CardFieldTemplateSelector class file not call at runtime

Comment: at runtime data template selector is not called. am i missing a reference to the class. should i specify more code for better understanding of the question?

Comment: Updated code. If data template selector is not called, sure that data context is correct and you have provided nessesary view model with CardField.FieldTag path

Comment: Please check my Updated part in which i have update my code which i am trying to do

Comment: You should bind IEnumerable<T> in ItemsSource and there will be T in DataContext of each item which described with DataTemplate. In your case T should have CardField.FieldTag.

Comment: I don't understand why CardFieldTemplateSelector class not called and get or set value in DataTemplate ?

Comment: any person give me the solutions of this problem

Comment: replace {Binding CardField.FieldTag... with {Binding Converter=...} and you can see that selector calls correctly, than look in debug what is the object comes in selector.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6181/discussion-between-ashwin-and-vladimir-dorokhov)

Answer (score 0):

Why can;t you use the WPF Data Form from [Codeplex](http://wpfdataform.codeplex.com/).

You can add custom editors in this form, based on the data types.

Hope this help.

Comment: no proper documentation to use it. And i m quiet new to WPF Databinding.